# How to understand when the user deletes text input?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget where I take input from the user. When the user inputs the variables normally and pushes the save button, there is no problem. When the user deletes the input after he/she gives some input, my app breaks. My question is: how can I understand when the user deletes the input and have my app correctly handle that?

```
Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                      ),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                        onChanged: (value){
                                            setState(() {
                                              _ingredients[index].ingredientAmount=value;
                                              categoryModels[widget.subCategoryId].subCategoryModels[widget.subCategoryCardId].ingredients[index].ingredientAmount=value;
                                              var flag=0;
                                              for(int i=0;i<=_ingredients.length-1;i++){
                                                if(_ingredients[i].ingredientAmount==null){
                                                 flag=-1;
                                                }
                                              }
                                              if(flag==-1){
                                                falseIngredientAmountSelected(context);
                                              }
                                              else{
                                                trueIngredientAmountSelected(context);
                                              }
                                            });
                                        },
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          border:OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          hintText: "Miktar Girin",
                                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      height: 50,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `onChanged`, first check `if(value.isNotEmpty)`. You can abort anything that is going to be done with the empty value by putting `return;` in case that `value.isNotEmpty` returns false. Also you could display a message that tells the user that the input should not be empty.

I also recommend using `onSubmitted` or `onEditingComplete` instead of `onChanged` so that it only checks or does something when the user finished inputting text and not after every character.